# Using brackets in glob patterns

Tags: bash

I am having difficulty deciding where to put the square bracketing in the following bash glob expression that is supposed to match a variable starting with `-` followed by any non-digit entry.

```
[[ "$var" == -*[^[0123456789]]* ]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "bracket expression" can be thought of as a *set* of characters: match one of these characters.

- you can list the individual characters

  ```
  [^0123456789]
  ```
- you can put a range of characters

  ```
  [^0-9]
  ```

  One drawback to this is that character ranges include different characters in  different locales.
- you can put a POSIX character class: this is where you see brackets inside brackets

  ```
  [^[:digit:]]
  ```

And you can mix-and-match the above.

This is all documented in manual: [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: I am confused about `[^0123456789]`, because `^` refers to a negation, whilst in the bracket term, it seems to mean the character `^`.  Manual does not mention `^` at all.

Comment: It does: "If the first character following the ‘[’ is a ‘!’ or a ‘^’ then any character not enclosed is matched."

Comment: Really missed that.